# Mixin functions only work in render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mixins

For some reason, it appears that mixin functions in my code only work properly in `render()` function. It could be that I'm not calling them in the right manner outside of the `render()`, but shouldn't it be exactly the same way?

This way everything works fine (but I can't stick with this since I have to add some extra stuff to click handling, at the same time not altering the mixin):

```
var Row = React.createClass({
    mixins: [someMixin]
    },

    render: function () {
        var clickHandler = null;
        var btn = null;

        if (firstCase) {
            clickHandler = this.order(this.props.name, this.props.else);
            btn = (<a href="" onClick={clickHandler}>Order</a>);
        } else if (secondCase) {
            clickHandler = this.noOrder(this.props.name, this.props.else);
            btn = (<a href="" onClick={clickHandler}>No order</a>);
        }
        return (
            <div>
                {btn}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

But when I do the obvious and include the mixin functions in another function to handle the click - like this - everything fails and even 'test' is not printed in the console:

```
var Row = React.createClass({
    mixins: [someMixin]
    },

    handleOrderClick(type) {
        console.log('test');
        if (type == 'order') {
            this.order(this.props.name, this.props.else);
        } else if (type == 'no-order') {
            this.noOrder(this.props.name, this.props.else);
        }
    },

    render: function () {
        var clickHandler = null;
        var btn = null;

        if (firstCase) {
            clickHandler = this.handleOrderClick('order');
            btn = (<a href="" onClick={clickHandler}>Order</a>);
        } else if (secondCase) {
            clickHandler = this.handleOrderClick('no-order');
            btn = (<a href="" onClick={clickHandler}>No order</a>);
        }
        return (
            <div>
                {btn}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

EDIT:
`order` and `noOrder` functions look like this:

```
order: function (name, else) {
    return function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var term = name + '&&¤%' + else;
        Order.order(name, else, period, function (data) {

            if (term === (global || window).MAIN_NAME + '.' + (global || window).MAIN) {
                $(window).trigger('Name:update');
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this);
},

noOrder: function (name, else) {
    return function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (!this.state.transferModalOpen) {
            this.toggleTransferModal();
        }
    }.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `this.setState` in `handleOrderClick` you'll have to use the `bind` method in your render method. Therefore `handleOrderClick` will become:

```
handleOrderClick(type, event) {
    this.setState({foo: 'bar'});
    if (type == 'order') {
        this.order(this.props.name, this.props.else)(event);
    } else if (type == 'no-order') {
        this.noOrder(this.props.name, this.props.else)(event);
    }
},
```

and your render method becomes:

```
render: function () {
    var clickHandler = null;
    var btn = null;

    if (firstCase) {
        clickHandler = this.handleOrderClick.bind(this, 'order');
        btn = (<a href="" onClick={clickHandler}>Order</a>);
    } else if (secondCase) {
        clickHandler = this.handleOrderClick(this, 'no-order');
        btn = (<a href="" onClick={clickHandler}>No order</a>);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {btn}
        </div>
    );
}
```

You'll notice that the functions that are returned by `this.order` and `this.noOrder` are no longer returned by `handleOrderClick`, but are instead executed immediately. This should provide the effect you desire.

I've put the code in your example into a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Martoid_Prime/18aj4atu/4/) and it now seems to be working correctly. I've had to change the prop 'else' to 'alt' because 'else' is a reserved word. I've also just applied the mixin to the class directly for simplicity. I have simpilfied the `order` and `noOrder` functions as I don't have access to the `Order` object and we are only interested in them firing at the correct time. I've also added a second button that you can click to flip the cases so the other button is rendered, causing the component to render again. I've added a label that will display which function had been called when the button was last pressed.

for reference, you can find more information about the bind method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

Hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks for the help! It got me going in the right direction, but I'm still struggling. If I add `return` as you suggested (brilliant idea by the way, I should have thought of that myself), then the functions are fired on click AND on rendering. To counter firing on render, I'm supposed to add `bind()`, but if I add that as well, then I'm back to square one and functions aren't fired at all. I also updated the original question with `order` and `noOrder` functions.

Comment: I've updated my answer given your edit. Let me know if you still have any problems =)

Comment: This works beautifully as long as I don't add `this.setState({});` in the click handler. That's what I meant when I said that it fires both on render and on click. For `console.log()` it is acceptable, but for `this.setState({})` it results in a react error, that you can't modify states in `render()`. How could I also modify a state on click?

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood =) If you want to `setState` when using `handleOrderClick`, the cleanest way I know is to use binding in your render method. I've edited my answer with the updated methods and jsfiddle, hopefully I solved it this time ^_^

Comment: Whoa, new stuff. :) No wonder I was in trouble, I haven't used (or even seen!) that kinda syntax before. But thank you very much, I'm sorted and applauding you!